# Getting foreground app's packageName in Marshmallow delayed by 3 seconds

Tags: android, package, android-6.0-marshmallow, foreground, usagestatsmanager

In Android 6.0 Marshmallow I query for the foreground app with the following code but there was a problem with incoming notifications because it shows foreground app to the app which sends notification. The problem exists only in Marshmallow (5.X works correctly).

```
// API 21 and above
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public static String getProcessNew(UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager, Context c) throws Exception {
        String st = null;
        try {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long beginTime = endTime - 1000 * 10;

            // We get usage stats for the last minute
            List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, beginTime,
                    endTime);
            // Sort the stats by the last time used
            if (stats != null) {
                SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                    mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                }
                if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                    st = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("main", "Wxxxxexx " + e);

        }
        return st;
    }
```

and then notification problem is solved using solution from this answer [UsageEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33748047/2452189).

As solution in answer I put the code and its working to get Foreground app but it delayed by 3 seconds. My service is checking foreground app and is repeating every 500ms but whatsapp package detects after 3 seconds of starting whatsapp. this is code of UsageEvents i use from above solution.

```
                                if (BuildV >= 23) {
                                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    long beginTime = endTime - 1000 * 10;
                                    UsageEvents usageEvents = mUsageStatsManager.queryEvents(beginTime, endTime);
                                    UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
                                    while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
                                        usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
                                    }
                                    if (st.equals(event.getPackageName())
                                            && event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
                                        pack = st;

                                    }
                                }
```