# Expansion of Status Bar by User distorts my getFrontPackage() functionality

Tags: android

I have a service that his main goal is to get the package name of the current visible app. This is the code that is responsible for it:

```
try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
                UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) service.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);
                long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, startTime, endTime);
                if (usageStatsList != null && usageStatsList.size() > 0) {
                    Collections.sort(usageStatsList, new UsageStatsComparator());
                    UsageStats mUsageStats = usageStatsList.get(0);
                    return mUsageStats.getPackageName();
                }

                else {
                if (!Utils.usageAccessGranted(service) && !directToSettingAlreadyTookPlace) {
                    launchUsageStatsSetting(service);
                }
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) service.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            return mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Getting Front Package Failed " + e.toString());
        return "";
    }
```

This is the Comparator I use:

```
public class UsageStatsComparator implements Comparator<UsageStats> {



    @Override
    public int compare(UsageStats lhs, UsageStats rhs) {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20)
        {
            long time1 = lhs.getLastTimeUsed();
            long time2 = rhs.getLastTimeUsed();
            if (time1 > time2) {
                return -1;
            } else if (time1 < time2) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return 0;

    }

}
```

This problem is on Lollipop and forward devices.

Everything works well, until the user expends the Status bar. once expanded I start getting packages related to Notifications, and the most problematic thing is when the user closes the status bar I am not getting the package of the visible app, I still get the last Package received when the status bar was open.

This causing a major issue to may desired functionality.

I tried the following approach:

1. Get notifies when the Status bar is extended. I searched deeply but the only solution I found can be handled only by an Activity, but in my case it is impossible, because I am working through a Service...
2. My Service is always showing a Notification in the Status bar as a Custom Remote View. I tried to find a way to know if the Notification is visible to the user, with no success.

Any one have an idea how to tackle it?

Comment: did you try getRunningAppProcesses() for above api 20 ?

Comment: @santoXme IgetRunningAppProcesses() will return a list of all processes running on the device. I have tried it before and I could not figure out which one is the front actviity. I have a feeling it is in my comparator. I edited my answer and added my comparoator

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution here:

[Android 6.0 Marshmallow UsageStatsManager issue when trying to retrieve foreground app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307042/android-6-0-marshmallow-usagestatsmanager-issue-when-trying-to-retrieve-foregrou)

The solution is to use UsageEvents
The key is checking if the front package you found have the following event type: Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND